# Finding the orthogonal vector of two 1 by 5 vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

Is there any method which can find the orthogonal vector of two $1$ by $5$ vector?
I mean if $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are $1$ by $5$ vectors, then how do i find a vector  $c$ which  $\vec c \cdot \vec a =0$ and $\vec c \cdot \vec b =0$ ?

At first, I want to use the cross product to find $\vec c$, however, the cross product can only be used in $3$ dimensions.

Comment: Well, you have two equations of $5$ variables. Find any solution to the system.

Comment: Consider that vectors in the dimension of $a$ and $b$ are defined with 5 variables, while orthogonality gives 2 equations. So, the system is underrepresented.

Comment: "however, the cross product can only be used in 3 dimensions."

This is wrong. The cross product can be used in one, two, three, and infinitely many dimensions.